# Table doesn't take any class inside of $.getJSON Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to create a table using a json array that I'm getting from a URL.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/",
    method: "GET"

}).done(function(data) {

    document.write('<table class="table table-striped">');
    document.write('<tr><th>ID</tr></th>');

    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        document.write('<tr><td>' + data[i].id + "</tr></td>");
    }

    document.write('<tr><th>PRICE</tr></th>');

    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        document.write('<tr><td>' + data[i].price_usd + "</tr></td>");
    }

    document.write('</table>'); 
})
```

In the console I see that the table is being created, but the class 'table' is not registering.

If I use

```
function getJson(yourUrl){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
    Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;          
}

var json = JSON.parse(getJson("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"))
```

and loop through the variable json I can use the class and it works just fine, however opening a Httpreq seems to be deprecated since it is synchronous.

Comment: You have your tr, th, td closing tags backwards (close the inner one before the outer one).

Comment: It still does the same thing

Comment: https://hastebin.com/axanucecos.js idk how to do the code tag

Comment: Still backwards on the headers: `</tr></th>`

Comment: Still the same problem https://hastebin.com/qoqijugoyo.js

Comment: You probably want to be appending child elements to the `body`, rather than using `document.write`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use innerHTML.

```
<div id="records"></div>
```

Use this code **100% working**

```js
$.ajax({
   url:"https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/",
   method: "GET"

}).done(function(data) {
   var html = '';
   html +='<table class="table table-striped">';
   html +='<tr><th>ID</th><th>PRICE</th></tr>';
   for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     html +='<tr><td>' + data[i].id + '</td><td>' + data[i].price_usd + '</td></tr>';
   }
   html +='</table>';
   var container = document.getElementById('records');
   container.innerHTML = html;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="records"></div>
```